# Install Plasma 5 KDE ubuntu - Cannot add PPA

Tags: kubuntu, kde, ppa

I am trying to install Plasma 5 KDE on my ubuntu 14.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-plasma5-desktop plasma-workspace-wallpapers
```

It fails after the first command with the message:

```
 Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next-backports'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I got all from the following link

http://sourcedigit.com/14871-install-kde-plasma-5-2-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-14-10/

What is this error-message and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ppa:kubuntu-ppa/next-backports` is a valid name for a PPA, but there is no PPA with this name. [Here](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa) is a list of valid PPAs of the “Kubuntu Package Archives” team.

- `backports` – Kubuntu Backports
- `beta` – Kubuntu Beta Backports
- `experimental` – Kubuntu Experimental
- `ppa` – Kubuntu Updates
- `staging-frameworks` – Kubuntu Staging Frameworks
- `staging-kdeapplications` – Kubuntu Staging KDE Applications
- `staging-misc` – Kubuntu Staging Misc
- `staging-plasma` – Kubuntu Staging Plasma

Therefore install an existing PPA, e.g.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Comment: A.B so the answer to resolve the question is? eg How the see available PPA on the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: You are not using any proxy servers

- Re-install the certificates,Use::-

  sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa

  Example ---  *sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:videolan/stable-daily*

  [*sudo -E preserves the user environment, including any proxy config* ]

Case 2: If you are using any proxy servers

1. Configure The Proxies in the Terminal

   ```
      If there is no username and password for the proxy settings ::-

           export http_proxy=http://proxy:port
           export https_proxy=http://proxy:port

      In case of Username and Password for the proxy settings use this ::-

        export http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port
        export https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port


      After this do::-
                 sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:ppaname/ppa
   ```

   Example ---  *sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:videolan/stable-daily*

   [*sudo -E preserves the user environment, including any proxy config* ]